# How to make renderUI change when the SQL database changes?

Tags: r, shiny

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(miniUI)
library(shinymanager)
library(RMariaDB)
library(DBI)

inactivity <- "function idleTimer() {
var t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);
window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

function logout() {
window.close();  //close the window
}

function resetTimer() {
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
}
}
idleTimer();"

# data.frame with credentials info
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("1", "fanny", "victor", "benoit"),
  password = c("1", "azerty", "12345", "azerty"),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
ui <- secure_app(head_auth = tags$script(inactivity), miniPage( 
  gadgetTitleBar("Welcome!"),
  miniTabstripPanel(
    miniTabPanel("Test", icon = icon("truck"),
                 
                   h2(" "),
                 uiOutput("wq_print"),
                 actionButton("finish", "Finish!", class = "btn btn-primary")#btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-success
                 
    )
    
) ) )

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  result_auth <- secure_server(check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials))
  
  output$res_auth <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(result_auth)
  })
  id=1
localuserpassword="MYPASSWORD"

con=dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='USER_NAME', password=localuserpassword, dbname='DBNAME', host='localhost')
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...) 

  wq = data.frame()
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame()

   ##### the problem is here -------------------------------------------################

  
   a <- reactive({ paste("SELECT COL1  FROM TABLE where id = ", id, sep="") })
  
   observe({
      wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })
      
      output$wq_print <- renderUI( { h1(wq()$COL1,align = "center") } )
      
       })
  
   ##### the problem is above-------------------------------------------################
    
  id=1
  localuserpassword <- "MYPASSWORD"
  storiesDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='USER_NAME', password=localuserpassword, dbname='DBNAME', host='localhost')
  querysel=paste("select COL1 from TABLE where id ='",id,"'",sep = ''  )
  rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,querysel)
  dbClearResult(rs)
  dbDisconnect(storiesDb)
     
  observeEvent(input$finish,{
    confirmSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      inputId = "Confirm",
      type = "question",
      title = "Do you want to confirm?",
      danger_mode = F,
      closeOnClickOutside = T,
      showCloseButton =T
    )
    observeEvent(input$Confirm, {
      if(isTRUE(input$Confirm)){
        Free="Free"
        localuserpassword="MYPASSWORD"
        storiesDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='USER_NAME', password=localuserpassword, dbname='DBNAME', host='localhost')
        query = paste("update TABLE set COL1= '",Free,"' where id ='",id,"' ",sep = '')
        rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,query)
        }
      
    } )
    
  })
  }
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How to make renderUI change when the SQL database changes? As the code is above, only update if I restart the app and I would like it to update whenever there is a change. The code problem is found inside the "##### ------  the problem is here" demarcation that I made for easier reading

I believe that this question answered would open up a lot of possibilities for R+Shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code (besides being not reproducible - please check [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) is that you `reactives` are not firing because the input they see does not change:

```r
a <- reactive({ paste("SELECT COL1  FROM TABLE where id = ", id, sep="") })
```

This reactive will fire once (when `id` changes) but never again (as `id` does not change). As a consequence:

```r
wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })
```

will not fire, because `a` remains constant.

It is not quiet clear what you want to achieve. Do you want that the `renderUI` fires whenever there is a new `id`? In this case you have to make `id` reactive on a user input or whatever.

If you want `renderUI` to fire whenever the *databases* changes, you can use [`reactivePoll`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html), which is meant to be used in such cases.

You would define a relatively cheap `check` function to find out whether a change was made to the database (e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE`). The check function is called periodically (as given by `intervalMillis`) and whenever this value changes the `valueFunc` is called, where you do your real database query (which is assumed to be heavier on resources).

Alternatively, you could use also something like this:

```r
get_data <- reactive({
 invalidateLater(1000) # tell r to invalidate this input every 1000 millisecs
 # your query
 dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = 1")
})
```

But this would query the database every `n` milliseconds and this may be an overkill if your query is rather heavy.